# AutoMapper ignoring extension method

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 models:

User.cs:

- Firstname
- Lastname
- Email
- Password

Authentication.cs

- Email
- Password

I would like the Email and Password from the Authentication model to map to the Email and Password within the User model so in my MappingProfile I have:

```
public UserProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, Authentication>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Email, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Email))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Password, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.Password))
            .IgnoreAllNonExisting();
    }
```

The IgnoreAllNonExisting is a custom extension like so:

```
   public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> IgnoreAllNonExisting<TSource, TDestination>
        (this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
    {
        var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
        var destinationProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties(flags);

        foreach (var property in destinationProperties)
        {
            if (sourceType.GetProperty(property.Name, flags) == null)
            {
                expression.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
            }
        }
        return expression;
    }
```

Despite the extension I still get this error:

Unmapped properties:Firstname;Lastname

It's almost as if my extension is just being ignored?

Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html#selecting-members-to-validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to create the mappings from *User* to *Authentication* and vice-versa (not one mapping for both directions).

Since the names of properties are the same for *User* and *Authentication* the AutoMapper makes the automatic mapping.

The extension method *IgnoreAllNonExisting* is not needed, the AutoMapper makes this work for you.

```
public static void Test01()
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<User, Authentication>();
        cfg.CreateMap<Authentication, User>();
    });

    var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

    var authentication = mapper.Map<User, Authentication>(new User { Email = "email", Password = "pass", Firstname = "first", Lastname = "last" });

    var user = mapper.Map<Authentication, User>(new Authentication { Email = "email", Password = "pass" });
}
```